# Springboot Testing via Greenmail

Tags: spring, spring-boot, smtp, spring-test, greenmail

I tried to test my Gmail smtp in my Spring-Application and followed this [Tutorial](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-mail-integration-testing-junit-greenmail-example/). I have implemented it as specified in the tutorial, but my EmailService throws a MailSendException:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 2525; timeout 5000;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 2525; timeout 5000;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 2525; timeout 5000;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2210)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:722)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342)
```

Has anyone a tip how to solve this? (Never tested something like SMTP/Email and therefore just followed the tutorial above.
EDIT: I can send emails without any problem manually, but I need to test it.
my application.yml:

```
spring.mail.host: smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port: 587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable: true
spring.mail.username: ************@gmail.com
spring.mail.password: ***************
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required: true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth: true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout: 5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout: 5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout: 5000
```

Comment: Which means there is nothing started at port 2525.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the log you can see, that Spring is trying to connect to port **2525** but can't make connection. That means that there's no running mail server on this port, during test execution - which should be provided by JUnit Rule implementation (If you're using JUnit5 use [Extensions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions))

Make sure that your test configuration is properly setup. That means, check whether your test code, e.g.

```
@Rule
public SmtpServerRule smtpServerRule = new SmtpServerRule(2525);
```

matches

`src/test/resources/application.yml`

```
spring:
  mail:
    default-encoding: UTF-8
    host: localhost
    jndi-name:
    username: username
    password: secret
    port: 2525
    properties:
      mail:
        debug: false
        smtp:
          debug: false
          auth: true
          starttls: true
    protocol: smtp
    test-connection: false
```

I would also recommend to update the code from the [Tutorial](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-mail-integration-testing-junit-greenmail-example/) and add test user - as it could be used with secured protocols.

```
public class SmtpServerRule extends ExternalResource {
// omitted for brevity
@Override
protected void before() throws Throwable {
   super.before();
   smtpServer = new GreenMail(new ServerSetup(port, null, "smtp"));
   smtpServer.addUser("username", "secret");
   smtpServer.start();
}
// omitted for brevity
}
```

Also, refer to the official [GreenMail documentation](https://greenmail-mail-test.github.io/greenmail/) for more specific setup.